# Japanese phrase about risk

Tags: expressions, pronunciation

I heard in anime a phrase related to risk, like "all or nothing". It sounded like "icka backa" but I can't find the exact phrase.

Comment: Possibly 一か八か https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%80%E3%81%8B%E5%85%AB%E3%81%8B

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's indeed `一か八か` (*ichi ka bachi ka*), meaning roughly "sink or swim", "all or nothing" etc.

Comment: Literally it means '[will it be] one or eight', in reference to a particular gambling game.